# Jssor Slider loading using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JSSor image slider from www.jssor.com
Here is a what is suppose to look like: http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html

This JSSOR image gallery lets me make makes changes to images and how many of them by adding and modifying these lines here:

```
<div>
     <img u="image" src="images/2A Wyresdale/b_01.jpg" />
     <img u="thumb" src="images/2A Wyresdale/t_01.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div>
      <img u="image" src="images/2A Wyresdale/b_02.jpg" />
      <img u="thumb" src="images/2A Wyresdale/t_02.jpg" />
</div>
```

The more div block i have the more images are added to the slider. **But i want to be able to use some kind of for loop.**

I tried using JS and php for loops.... an example:

```
<?php
    for ($img = 0; $img < 9; $img++) {
        echo '<img u="image" src="images/2A Wyresdale/b_' . $img . '.jpg" />';
        echo '<img u="thumb" src="images/2A Wyresdale/t_' . $img . '.jpg" />';
    }
?>
```

Not working using these type of technics

help me please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to check the output slides html format is correct.

It seems the '<div></div?' is missing.

Please open your page with browser, and check html code by 'view source'.

Comment: Thank you.
It turns out that it was a directory issues "../../" and also i didnt included <div>. By checking out the right html format.